# Speed of online backups with BLOBs

Tags: database, oracle, blob

In Oracle 8 doing an online backup with BLOBs in the database is extremely slow. By slow, I mean over an hour to backup a database with 100MB of BLOB data. Oracle acknowledged it was slow, but wouldn't fix the problem (so much for paying for support.) Does anyone know if Oracle has fixed this problem with subsequent releases? Also, how fast do online backups work with BLOBs work in SQL Server and MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue in the past, and the only decent workarounds we found were to make sure that the LOBs were in their own tablespace, and use a different backup strategy with them, or to switch to using the BFILE type.  Whether or not you can get by with BFILE will depend on how you're using the LOBs.

Some usage info on BFILE:

http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oralob.htm#1059942

Note that BFILEs live on the filesystem outside of Oracle, so you'd need to back them up in a process outside of your normal Oracle backup.  On one project we just had a scheduled rsync to offsite backup.  Also important to note is that you cannot create/update BFILEs via JDBC, but you can read them.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about the speed of online backups of BLOBs in SQL Server, it's the same speed as backing up regular data for SQL 2000/2005/2008 - it's typically limited by the speed of your storage.  I usually get over 100mb/sec on my database backups with BLOBs.

Be wary of using backup compression tools with those, though - if the BLOB is binary-style data that's heavily random, then you'll waste CPU cycles trying to compress the data, and compression can make the backup slower instead of faster.

Answer (score 0):

I use SQL Backup from Redgate for SQL Server -- it is ridiculously fast, even with my BLOB data.

I keep a copy of every file that I do EDI with, so while they aren't huge, they are numerous and BLOBs.  I'm well over 100Megs of just these text files.

It's important to note that Redgate's SQL Backup is just a front-end to the standard SQL Backup...it gives you additional management features, basically, but still utilizes the SQL Server backup engine.

Comment: This question was about Oracle

Comment: No, the question specifically says, "Also, how fast do online backups work with BLOBs work in SQL Server and MySQL?"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the BLOBs, make sure you're storing them in-line / out of line appropriately.

See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_table_blob_lob_storage.htm

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the export file you're creating and the Oracle tablespaces on different disks?  You I/O throughput may be the constraining factor...?

Answer (score 0):

exp on 8i was slow, but not as much as you describe. I have backed-up gigabytes of blobs in minutes in 10g..(to disk - using expdp)